# Issue of OpenGL implementation

Tags: iphone, xcode, opengl-es

> glCheckError: 0501 caught at /Users/mac/Documents/PhotoFrameApp/PhotoFrameApp/Debug.c:177

Any idea what this error could be?

This is a debugging error where I tried to implement OpenGL for increasing, decreasing the brightness, contrast etc of a UIImage using the GLImageProcessing sample from Apple. The app does not crash but it does not work either.

The View has a UITabbar containing the different effects like brightness, contrast, hue etc and a UISlider that is used for increasing or decreasing them.

The code implemented is :-

```
int b, i;
tabBar.selectedItem = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, 30, 30, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
CGImageRef theCGImage = imageCollage.image.CGImage;

// Draw with white round strokes
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

for (b = 0; b < NUM_BUTTONS; b++)
{
    CGContextClearRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30));

    switch(b)
    {
        case BUTTON_BRIGHTNESS:
        {
            const CGFloat line[8*4] = {
                15.0, 6.0, 15.0, 4.0,
                15.0,24.0, 15.0,26.0,
                6.0,15.0,  4.0,15.0,
                24.0,15.0, 26.0,15.0,
                21.5,21.5, 23.0,23.0,
                8.5, 8.5,  7.0, 7.0,
                21.5, 8.5, 23.0, 7.0,
                8.5,21.5,  7.0,23.0,                    
            };

            // A circle with eight rays around it
            CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(10.5, 10.5, 9.0, 9.0));
            for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                CGContextMoveToPoint(context, line[i*4+0], line[i*4+1]);
                CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, line[i*4+2], line[i*4+3]);
                CGContextStrokePath(context);                   
            }
            break;
        }
- (void)sliderAction:(id)sender{
// Redraw the view with the new settings
obj = [[EAGLView alloc]init];
[obj drawView];}

- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{
// Recenter the slider (this application does not accumulate multiple filters)
//slider setValue:1.0 animated:YES];
// Redraw the view with the new settings
[obj drawView];}
```

Comment: So, what is at that line? Or what happens before it in your code? Show us the code. You might be passing an invalid value to some OpenGL functionality somewhere.

Comment: I hav added the code but it is almost the same as that of Apples GLImageProcessing sample which I have been trying to implement in my app.

Comment: FWIW, error 501 is GL_INVALID_VALUE. Which line is l.177 ?

Comment: I don't even see any OpenGL code here..

Comment: Are you running in the simulator or on hardware. My experience from a few years ago is that the simulator isn't anything like the real thing.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802007/how-to-fix-glcheckerror-and-alos-snapshot-issue-in-eaglview